# How to create license of Powerbuilder 12.6 for virtual Machine?

Tags: powerbuilder

**How to create license for Powerbuilder 12.6 for virtual Machine?** I think there is a different procedure to create licence for Local Machine and Virtual Machine. Please help me out from this.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked places where PowerBuilder 12.6 is used on virtual machines.

- You need to have a user id to access SAP support articles and software.
- Establish a SYSAM server that is visible to the virtual machine. (Software download link is included in full article details below.)
- Generate SAP PowerBuilder license keys and download the file to the $SYBASE/SYSAM-2_0/licenses which for me was c:\sybase\SYSAM-2_0\licenses (More information here: https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2667250)
- Restart the SYSAM server

This article provides full details.

https://blogs.sap.com/2016/11/08/installing-and-administering-sysam-server-for-powerbuilder-infomaker/

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I haven’t been able to get this to work because the Sybase’s/SAP’s SySam licensing won’t work under Remote Desktop. (I suppose the fear was install one IDE centrally and multiple people using it.) If there’s a way around this, I haven’t heard of it.

Don’t think this will be applicable to the Appeon versions of PowerBuilder and their new licensing scheme, from what I’ve heard, but I don’t have firsthand knowledge.